# How can I iterate through an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array called tables that I need to iterate through, but in my current code it is iterating and then stopping at the first index of the array ignoring the rest of the values in the array.

My code:

```
async function scrapeSiteYield(){

    var yield = [];
    var country = [];
    
    const yieldResult = await axios.get("https://tradingeconomics.com/forecast/government-bond-10y");

    const $ = cheerio.load(yieldResult.data);
    var tables = ["8","12","16","20","24"];
    var count = 1;
    tables.forEach(function (item, index) {
        var scrapeStatus = false;
        while (!scrapeStatus) {
            var res = {};
            $(`#aspnetForm > div.container > div > div > div:nth-child(${item}) > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(${count}) > td.datatable-item-first`).each((index, element) => {
                console.log(item);
                console.log($(element).text().trim());
                res.country = $(element).text().trim();
            });
            if (res.country == null || res.country === undefined) {
                scrapeStatus == true;
                break;
            }
            else{
                count++;
                yield.push(res);
            }
        }
      });
}
scrapeSiteYield();
```

My result:

```
8
UK
8
Germany
8
Russia
8
Italy
8
France
8
Switzerland
8
Czech Republic
8
Ireland
8
Portugal
```

So the values 12,16,20,24 in my table array is not being iterated through, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You actually never assign `true` to `scrapeStatus`.

This code

```js
            if (res.country == null || res.country === undefined) {
                scrapeStatus == true;
                break;
            }
```

Should look like this:

```js
            if (res.country == null || res.country === undefined) {
                scrapeStatus = true;
            }
```

1- The `while` clause will break when `scrapeStatus` is true according to your code. No need to add a break.

2- Assign `true` to `scrapeStatus` instead of checking if it's `true`.

Comment: Thank you @Pierre Janineh, I made the adjustments but my result is the same (Updated code below): `   
 
            if (res.country == null || res.country === undefined) {
                scrapeStatus = true;
               
            }
            else{
                count++;
                yield.push(res);
            }
        }
      });`

Answer (score 0):

You have two loops. The jQuery loop `each()` is inside the `tables.forEach()` loop, meaning that it will loop through all elements with the same item from tables array.

To fix this you need to itirate the tables array inside the `each()` loop, something like so:

```
elements.each((index, element) => {
    let tableIndex = 0;

    if(index < tables.length){
       tableIndex = index;
    }
    console.log(tables[tableIndex]);
    console.log($(element).text().trim());
    res.country = $(element).text().trim();
});
```